# How to display all the text of swing application in Indian regional language (Marathi)

Tags: java, swing, localization, internationalization, locale

I am working on the desktop application in java (Swing).
In my application there are some jTextField, Jlable and JtextArea.
e.g.

```
(Jlable)First Name: -----(JtextField)
(Jlable)Last Name: -----(JtextField)
```

etc.

So here is my actual question. Jlable, Jtextfield and JtextArea i.e. all component are by default displayed in english language.
Like `First Name, Last Name` But I want to displayed it in `Indian regional language (Marathi)`, something like `प्रथम नाव`  instead of `First Name`.

For this I have created one `.properties` file and store `FirstName=प्रथम नाव`.
I am using NetBeans IDE, so from the properties of this `First Name` `Jlable` I have loaded .properties file `"FirstName"` key's value.
But I am not able to see the `प्रथम नाव` at the place of `First Name` `Jlable`.
I just seen something like `[][][][][][]`.

So how can I achive this, i.e. to display all the text in `Marathi` language.

Any help will appreciated.Thanks

Comment: How have you created your properties file? It looks like you have something wrong with encoding. You need to read the properties file in econding that it was written. If you have used non standard tool to edit it, it will give you such things. Please use properties editor to edit this file.

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html).

Comment: It's not about encoding, it's about the font. Clearly, the default one (Dialog font) can't display these letters. Which means PKH has to set fonts by hand. If I were to use Swing for UI again, I would probably derive from standard controls and and set fonts in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to have is shivaji font in your computer.
If you have them (check in control panel) then you can use the following code:

```
label name.set text("Aan");
label name.setFont(new Font("Shivaji02"),Font.BOLD,23);
```

Here *23* is the size of font